# How to insert a column with serial number in shell?

Tags: linux, shell, awk

I have a file with 4 colums.

```
ifile.txt
2 3 4 2
2 3 4 1
4 3 4 3
4 5 3 5
. . . .
```

I need to insert a column for serial number like:

```
ofile.txt
1 2 3 4 2
2 2 3 4 1
3 4 3 4 3
4 4 5 3 5
5 . . . .
. . . . .
```

I was trying using `awk` , but unsuccessful

```
awk '{print i, $1, $2, $3, $4}' ifile.txt > ofile.txt
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use the built-in `NR` which is a 1-based record counter.

```
awk '{print NR, $1, $2, $3, $4}' ifile.txt > ofile.txt
```

The general-purpose form is:

```
awk '{print NR, $0}'
```

That will print out the entire record (prefixed by its sequence number), regardless of how many fields there are.

Answer (score 2):

Alternatively you can use the `nl` which will give you more control on formatting

```
nl filename
```

or, for basic numbering

```
cat -n filename
```